# UITextField change placeholder color when it become first Responder

Tags: uitextfield

Is there any way to change the first responder UITextField's placeholder color? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the UITextField placeholder color on first responder event as like in its delegate method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField setValue:[UIColor yellowColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    return YES;
}
```